# Matrix of the dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:P_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow P_2(\mathbb{R})$, $T(p(x))=2xp'(x)$, and the linear forms of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$:
> $$
> f_1(p(x))=p(0),\ f_2(p(x))=p'(0),\ f_3(p(x))=\int_0^2p(x)dx.
> $$
> Find the matrix of $T$ from the basis $p=\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ which is the dual of $f_i$.

---

Let $p_i=a_ix^2+b_ix+c_i, i=1,2,3$

first I found the basis $p$, by solving the equations $f_i(p_j)=δ_{ij}$

$f_1(p_1(x))=1, f_2(p_2(x))=0$ $\dots  $ ect
and i found that

$p_1(x)=\frac{-6}{8}x^2+1$

$p_2(x)=\frac{-6}{8}x^2+x$

$p_3(x)=\frac{8}{3}x^2$

then i apply $T$

$T(p_1(x))=\frac{-24}{8}x^2=\frac{-9}{8}p_3$

$T(p_2(x))=\frac{-24}{8}x^2+2x=2p_2-\frac{9}{16}p_3$

$T(p_3(x))=\frac{32}{3}x^2=4p_3$

and therefore  the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &2  &0 \\ 
\frac{-9}{8} &\frac{-9}{16}  &4 
\end{pmatrix}$

**Is this correct?**

**In order to find $T^t$ I just take** ${\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &2  &0 \\ 
\frac{-9}{8} &\frac{-9}{16}  &4 
\end{pmatrix}}^t$ ?

Comment: I think you got the fraction in $p_3$ flipped, which leads to a couple subsequent errors.

Comment: What you mean by flipped ?